# How to create cartesian product of a MultiIndex including dates within a range but not in the Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex (date, state and article) and a values column (quantity). I need to upsample the DataFrame to include a line for each state, article, and date within a range combination. This so I can perform a rolling sum for each line.

I tried creating a new index using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)` and re-indexing my DataFrame with it but if certain dates within the range are missing from the original DataFrame it won't have all the lines necessary.

I've also tried creating a list using `pd.date_range`, and then using `apply` on the GroupBy Object to re-index each part. But was unsuccessful.

Finally I've also thought of appending blank lines for the full list of dates to the DataFrame but that would result in blanks in my state and article levels.

Here's what I have right now:

DF:

```
                             quantity
    date       state article
    2019-06-02 CA    3431    12
    2019-06-04 CA    2584    48
```

Code:

```py
complete_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=index_cols)
df = df.reindex(complete_index)
```

Output:

```
                             quantity
    date       state article
    2019-06-02 CA    3431    12
    2019-06-04 CA    3431    
    2019-06-02 CA    2584
    2019-06-04 CA    2584    48
```

Desired Output where range is between min and max date (inclusive):

```
                             quantity
    date       state article
    2019-06-02 CA    3431    12
    2019-06-03 CA    3431
    2019-06-04 CA    3431
    2019-06-02 CA    2584
    2019-06-03 CA    2584    
    2019-06-04 CA    2584    48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way create the index by `groupby` then `reindex`

```
df1=df.reset_index().copy()
import functools
l=[pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(y.date.min(),y.date.max()),[x],y.article.unique()]) for x , y in df1.groupby('state') ]
idx=functools.reduce(lambda x , y : x.append(y),l)
df=df.reindex(idx)
                    quantity
2019-06-02 CA 3431      12.0
              2584       NaN
2019-06-03 CA 3431       NaN
              2584       NaN
2019-06-04 CA 3431       NaN
              2584      48.0
```